# Passing txt file into a pandas datafram

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

[image]

I have a txt file in such a format attached as per screenshot.  How can I convert this into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: You have to write a parser, or cleanup the file to have a csv-like format. What have you tried on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    read_file = pd.read_csv(r'...\file_name.txt')

    #write file in csv format into a directory
    read_file.to_csv (r'...\new_file_name.csv', index=None)
```

Where *"...\file_name.txt"* is the directory of the file followed by the file name.
Than open the csv. If it doesn't work you will need to clean up the file first and separate the columns and values with `';'`